# Compilation error in UVA 11854

Tags: java, compiler-errors

This is the link for the actual problem, [here](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&category=&problem=2954&mosmsg=Submission%20received%20with%20ID%2014537008)

I have submitted my code multiple times, but each time it had a compilation error. The original message was

```
"Main.java:4: error: class Egypt is public, should be declared in a file named Egypt.java
public class Egypt {
       ^
1 error"
```

I have no idea where I went wrong. I have copied my code for the problem below. please help me with this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Egypt {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (true){
             int[] arr = new int[3];
             for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
             arr[i] = input.nextInt();

             if((arr[0]+arr[1]+arr[2])==0)
                    return;
             Arrays.sort(arr);

             int d = (int)(Math.pow(arr[0],2) + Math.pow(arr[1], 2));

             if(Math.sqrt(d)==arr[2])
                System.out.println("right");
             else
                System.out.println("wrong");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Well the clue is in the compilation error. It's complaining that `Main.java` isn't called `Egypt.java`. If you can't change the name of the source file, change the name of the class...

Comment: (or remove the `public` modifier)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Java specifications here](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=15&Itemid=30),

> All programs must begin in a static main method in a Main class.
>
> Do not use public classes: even Main must be non public to avoid compile error.

So, I think you must use

```
class Main
```